# What mobile platforms could I reliably expect this application concept to work on?

Tags: mobile

I need the ability to do the following things:

1) read the phone numbers out of received sms messages.

2) send an sms message.

3) finally, this one isn't necessary but would be a bonus: cause the phone to vibrate.

From what I can tell this wouldn't be possible on iphone or windows mobile, what other phone types cannont do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will probably not work on iPhone, considering the limitation on all applications in an iPhone. (Apps are in their own little world so to speak)

Vibration: All that supports vibration.

Sounds to me like you should focus on Android, where you will be able to do all of your mentioned things.